# Java Not Updating Url Contents

Tags: java, url

I have a `.txt` file which I read entirely via [`url`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) with the following code:

```
public static String getFileContents(String internetAddress)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(internetAddress);
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
    StringBuffer textBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    int readInteger = 0;

    while ((readInteger = inputStream.read()) != -1)
    {
        textBuffer.append((char) readInteger);
    }

    // Prevent resource leakage
    inputStream.close();

    return textBuffer.toString();
}
```

Usage example:

```
String text = getFileContents("http://www.example.com/file.txt");
```

When I update `file.txt` on the server via an ftp client like [`FileZilla`](https://filezilla-project.org/) my browser and `FileZilla` then show that the file has been updated but when I run the Java code above to retrieve its contents the variable `text` does not contain the current data but rather the previous/initial.

Why does it not fetch the newest data on every execution and how do I fix it? There is no [`cache`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) on repeated program executions, is there?

Comment: You should first close the InputStream to prevent resource leakage. I wouldn't bet on it, but maybe that also has the positive side effect of fixing your problem.

Comment: @HeinBlöd:
Alright but that still doesn't fix the issue.